# SQLite : Adding a row only if results in unique rows

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

My SQLite table looks like this.

```
                     ---------------------------
                    |_id|str A  |str B  |str C  |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |1  |cat    |blahty |lio    |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |2  |dog    |blahty |timmy  |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |3  |cow    |blahty |lio    |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |4  |bat    |blah   |timmy  |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |5  |tuna   |blahty |timmy  |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |6  |cat    |bla    |lio    |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |7  |dog    |blahty |timmy  |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |8  |cow    |bla    |lion   |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |9  |bat    |blahty |timmy  |
                    |---------------------------|
                    |10 |tuna   |blahty |lio    |
                     ---------------------------
```

An I have an `Array {new str A, new str B, new srt C}` from which I want to insert values to respective columns. I want to do this only if `new str A` don't match any entry in column `str A`. And I also want to `str A` unique by removing multiple occurances of `str A`. How do I accomplish this via SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use INSERT or IGNORE : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html when inserting into the table?

I think you would also have to make Col A a unique identifier in the table

Answer (score 0):

First get all the values from `str A` column then compare the value with your array value

Comment: Please explain a bit more, I'm new to sql.

Comment: You have a table in your sqlite database right, using cursor get all the str A column values put them in a list, then compare the array value with the list value

Answer (score 0):

One way you could have unique entries with str A is that you can make str A as the primary key instead of the _id and then use UPDATE to change the related values. This way, multiple occurances of str A will also be prevented, as the code will throw error when u try to INSERT an entry with a value of str A already present in the table. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: i guess any string or vchar can be made primary key.. primary key need  not be integer